# 'Warning: Non-executables were installed to "bin" ' when installing elasticsearch via homebrew

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, homebrew, railscasts

I'm following this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/306-elasticsearch-part-1) to get elasticsearch going in my rails app.  When I install it using homebrew like the railscast shows, I get this warning

```
Warning: Non-executables were installed to "bin".
Installing non-executables to "bin" is bad practice.
The offending files are:
/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/0.19.3/bin/elasticsearch.in.sh
```

this warning doesn't show up in the railscast when he installs it using the same homebrew command.  Did I mess anything up along the way?  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The railscast predates this particular warning.

It is there so that the Homebrew developers can find and clean up packages that are doing nasty things, but it doesn't affect actual use of the software.